# Suggested fermentation temperature for the beer kits

Tags: fermentation, temperature, temperature-control

Suggested fermentation temperature on the beer kit is ambient temperature or its the temperature reading on fermentation bucket? Also i am not able to keep steady ambient temperature as our flat's heating system is not modern it changes during the day, what effects that will have on my beer?

*Additional information:*
Temperature difference between wort and surrounding is generally around 3°C, and ambient temperature of the room also changes around 2°C throughout the day. I made couple of batches in these conditions they turned out ok, but I am wondering how important to control temperature precisely and will it really improve the quality; is it worth to make some investment for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reading to monitor and maintain is the temperature of the beer, not ambient temperature.

Even temp readings on the outside of fermentors from thermal stickers can vary a few degrees to what the core temp in the middle actually is.

Brewers never regret the investment into good temperature control based on thermal wells with a temp prob in beer.

Answer (score 1):

If the temperature differences are not that significant it will be fine. The beer takes a lot of time to change temperature due to its large volume, so usually over the course of a day it would not have the same temperature swings as its surrounding.

The suggested temps are of the beer itself and don’t forget the fermentation process produces some heat at its peek, so storing it some degrees lower could be a good idea.

I’ve done kits without heating/cooling, usually in a bathroom space where temperatures are relative stable throughout the day.

Comment: Temperature difference between wort and surrounding is generally around 3 degrees Celsius, and ambient temperature of the room also changes around 2 degrees throughout the day, I made couple of batches in these conditions they turned out ok, but i am wondering how important to control temperature precisely and will it really improve the quality/is it worth to make some investment for this.

Comment: Nah those temperature fluctuations are minimal, and therefore the quality improvement as well I think. But a fridge the regulate temperatures could also be used for e.g. brewing in the summer or cold crashing/lagering which do improve quality in my opinion...

Comment: Thanks, will go with current setup for now, but i think in future i should build a brewing fridge something like this example http://www.berrybrew.co.uk/fermentation-fridge-build-brew-fridge/

Answer (score 0):

After sanitation and brew day process, fermentation temp is pretty important. 
but not as important as keeping it stable.

When i started brewing, i would just put my buckets is any stable temp room. but what really brought my quality up was keeping my buckets in a big tub of water to keep it cooler then amb. temp and to keep the heat from going up and down too much.

Answer (score 0):

Fermentation can generate large amounts of heat, it is well worth the investment in good monitoring and control systems for the temperature of your brews.

You will often get good results without temperature control if your room is at a moderate temperature, but consistency between brews will not be there without good control.